# How can I download data from online table quickly?

Tags: dataset

I am trying to do download all the marathon results from 1996 to 2016 from the following link. There are more than 400000 entries, but I can only show 1000 results per page.

Is there any way that can let me download all of them quickly?

Thanks in advance!

http://chicago-history.r.mikatiming.de/2015/

Comment: Try instead https://github.com/llimllib/bostonmarathon

Comment: Try Scrapy (a Python framework that can also be used with other languages like Java, et cetera)

Comment: i'll scrape the data for you for a cost??? lemme know!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be an easy way - there is no mention of an API to get the data programmatically.

You could try contacting them via Twitter or something. Perhaps they would be happy to give you a dump of the data.

Otherwise, you might have to go down the route of writing a scraper e.g. using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). That would allow you to:

1. execute the search
2. download the file
3. navigate to the next search results page
4. repeat from step 2. until finished

They might be fairly easy, but do respect the websites wishes - perhaps they have a file called `robots.txt` which will tell you if they mind you doing that or not. In any case, build some `time.sleep()`s into your code, as not to bombard their server!

Comment: They do indeed have a robots.txt. It forbids all scrapers: http://chicago-history.r.mikatiming.de/robots.txt
(An introduction to robots textfiles: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)